# Selecting and deleting a list of words from whole panda data frame in python

Tags: python

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e12ki.png)
So i have a large data set and i want to remove all the row containing multiple words like ('test', 'TEST', 'Test')
I am not sure how to do it. I tried one way like this:

```
test_remove=df[df['Column1'].str.contains('test') 
|df['Column2'].str.contains('test') 
|df['Column3'].str.contains('test') 
|df['Column1'].str.contains('Test')
|df['Column2'].str.contains('Test') 
|df['Column3'].str.contains('Test')].index
```

Now to remove it from dataframe

```
df.drop(test_remove, inplace=True)
```

However, this works but with too many columns and multiple keyword i have to write a very long code to get this answer.
is there any shorter way to do this by selecting all the rows contain list of words to be removed and than remove if from dataframe.
Thanks

Comment: How many keywords do you have, and what are some more examples of them?

Comment: These are all of the words
     words=['test','Test','TEST','Tets','TETS','TEst']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically generate a string with all the statements and then evaluate it with `eval`:

```
# List of columns to check
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
# List of words to check
words = ['test', 'TEST', 'Test']

test_remove = df[eval('|'.join(f"df['{col}'].str.contains('{word}')"
                               for col in columns
                               for word in words))]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A': ['x', 'test', 'this', 'that'],
        'B': ['y', 'z', 'a', 'b'],
        'C': ['z', 'y', 'TEST', 'me']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
columns = df.columns
words = ['test', 'TEST', 'Test']
mask = 1
for col in columns:
    for word in words:
        mask = mask & ~df[col].str.contains(word)

df = df[mask]
```

Output

```
      A  B   C
0     x  y   z
3  that  b  me
```

Comment: Can you please explain why we using mask=1?

Also when i run this, i will get the following error  

    AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: mask=1 just to initialize mask. You can set it to True. AttributeError means that some of your data is not string. Try set dtype to str.

Comment: df['column_name'].apply(str)

Comment: For this should i convert all the columns to str?
i uploaded the sample data aswell, if you can take a look at it please.
thanks

Comment: Before do some computation, you can read the file as strings: df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=str) and clean up your data. After than you can convert columns to an appropriate data type.

Comment: ah okay okay. Thank you so much for this:)

Comment: Instead of columns = df.columns, you can pick column names yourself. columns = ['Order Status', 'Shipping Method'] or whatever.

Comment: Now  after converting to str, i am getting following error:
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'